# How can I use environment variables properly?

Tags: javascript, react-native, environment-variables

Im developing a white label app and I would like to know how can I use environment variables to generate specific color values and source images for different environments/builds.

Im using `react-native-config` to be able to manipulate/use env variables for my code specific builds.

```
//.env.fistapp
APP_BUILD=Environment-firstapp

LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE=./images/1Logo.png

LOGIN_SOME_BOOL=true

LOGIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR=#333
LOGIN_SIMPLE_TEXT_COLOR=#FFF
LOGIN_TEXTINPUT_BACKGROUD_COLOR=#FFF
LOGIN_LOGIN_BUTTON_COLOR=#009933
```

For color values its working fine like this:

```
<View styles={background: ${Config.LOGIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR}}/>
```

For booleans I dont know the proper way to do it.. Env variables are always `string` so I guess the workaround is:

```
<Switch value={Config.LOGIN_SOME_BOOL === "true"}/>
```

But im having difficulties for source images. I get:

```
Invalid call at line 18: require(_reactNativeConfig.default.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE) at C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\myproject\whitelabel\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:318:19
```

I have tryed all this ways:

`import Logo from Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE`

```
import Logo from `${Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE}`
```

`const Logo = Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE`

`<Image source={require(Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE)}/>`

`<Image source={{uri: require(Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE)}}/>`

Comment: Hi LuizfBrisighello, can you provide us with an example of what you are trying to accomplish ? Or a snippet of code so we can help you. As of now we have very little information.

Comment: @EduardVoiculescu Just added more info. Thanks for the headsup!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put this string in quotes: `LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE="../../images/1Logo.png"`. As for the booleans, print out `typeof(Config.LOGIN_SOME_BOOL)` and if its a bool you need to do `{Config.LOGIN_SOME_BOOL === true}` (no quotes)

Comment: Putting the quotes didnt work for me. And `typeof(Config.LOGIN_SOME_BOOL)` returns `string`.. I guess `Config.LOGIN_SOME_BOOL === "true"` will do for now..

Comment: Yes that should work, have you tried `<Image source={{uri: require(Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE)}}/>`?

Comment: `<Image source={{uri: require(Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE)}}/>` didnt work either.. Im getting very confused..

Comment: What about `import Logo from Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE` at the top and then `<Image source={Logo}/>`?

Comment: No deal with `import Logo from Config.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE` either